# SFML Failed to bind listener socket to port

Tags: c++, networking, sfml

I am trying to set up a connection to a local network with SFML. When I try to run this code I am getting a `Failed to bind listener socket to port 8062`. I've tried other ports as well. The machine I am trying to run this on is able to run networking through python just fine.

This code worked fine on a different machine when I was testing it earlier. I am fairly new to networking so not sure what's wrong.

This is all being called from a parent fork.

```
 76                 sf::TcpListener listener;
 77                 sf::TcpSocket socket;
 78 
 79                 if (!mode) {
 80                         listener.setBlocking(true);
 81 
 82                         listener.listen(8062);
 83                         cout << 1 << endl;
 84                         listener.accept(socket);
 85 
 86                         listener.setBlocking(false);
 87                 }
```